# Set correct variable in picker depending chosen value

Tags: react-native

I'm a newbie in react native. Currently what I'm trying to achieve is the following:

> My application contains 2 pickers: 1 for **places to ea**t and the other for the **menu's**

The "**Eating places**" picker contains the following options:

```
 var foodPlaces=["Taco Bell","Mc Donald","TGI Friday's","Hooters"];

 <Picker
        style={{a style there}}
        mode="dropdown"
        selectedValue={this.state.selected}
        onValueChange={()=>{}}> 
        {foodPlaces.map((item, index) => {
            return (<Picker.Item label={item} value={index} key={index}/>) 
        })}
    </Picker>
```

Now for each food places, I have their own  menu defined in an array:

```
var tacoBell = ["Enchilada","Fiesta Fries","Burrito with fries"];

var mcDonals = ["Menu 1,"Menu 2","Menu 3"];
```

etc..

What I'm trying to achieve is that, depending what eating places the user has chosen in the first picker, they will see it's corresponding menu in the second "**menu**" picker. Both of  those pickers are on the same page/screen.

My question is: is that even possible and if so, how can I achieve that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just think of the Picker as a visual representation. No value is stored in the Picker, so you can't retrieve items from it.

Instead what you need to do is store the selected value in your state:

So for your Eating places you might do:

```
selectedValue={this.state.selectedPlace}
onValueChange={ value => this.setState({ selectedPlace: value })}>
```

And for your menu you might do:

```
selectedValue={this.state.selectedMenu}
onValueChange={ value => this.setState({ selectedMenu: value })}>
```

Now in your code you can reference those values as `this.state.selectedPlace` and `this.state.selectedMenu` and respond to them accordingly.

The easiest way I could think to implement this is to have an object with keys equal to that of your restaurant names, for example

```
const menus = {
  "Taco Bell": ["Enchilada", "Fiesta Fries", "Burrito with fries"]
}
```

As long as those property names matched the values passed to your selector **exactly**, you could do something like this for your second picker:

```
render(){
  const { selectedPlace, selectedMenu } = this.state
  return (
    <Your Picker Coder .... >
    <Picker
      //your props>
    {menus[this.state.selectedPlace].map(menu => <Picker.Item ... />)}
    </Picker>
  )
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.